# Is it possible to style the same component different in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a generic component I want to re-use throughout my app. The problem is that I want to style it differently for various parts of the site. Is this possible?

I'm guessing there's a way to pass in a path for the styleUrl, but that seems really messy and i'm hoping there's a better alternative.

I also tried this but it didn't work: When specifying the component, add in the class, something like this

```
<generic-component class="customStyle1"></generic-component>
```

and then added styling based on customStyle1 into generic-component's stylesheet, but it didn't seem to pick up on the style.

Comment: You could add a customClass property on the component and specify what you need in each instance.

Comment: Updated OP. Is that what you meant? I tried and it didn't work.

Comment: You might have issues with that due to [View Encapsulation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#view-encapsulation). Either try to specify it as None on the component or add the custom classes into a main.css file not tied to a specific component.

Comment: My approach for your situation is not using the same component, is instead of repeating the code for each component, is make one HTML, one ts, and then every component that has a different look has a reference to the same HTML, the same TS but different CSS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may use `:host-context` in the style to theme your `component` based upon some class applied where it is being used.

Read more about it [here!!](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html)

**test.css**

```
:host-context(.theme-green) h3 {
   background-color: green;
}

:host-context(.theme-red) h3 {
   background-color: red;
}
```

**app.component**

```
import { Component }  from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h3 class="title">Basic Angular 2</h3>
    <my-test class="theme-green" ></my-test>
    <my-test class='theme-red' ></my-test>
   `
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(){}
}
```

**test.component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-test',
  template: `<h3>Test Component</h3>
  `,
 styleUrls : ['./app/test.css']
})
export class TestComponent {
 constructor(){}
}
```

Here is the [Plunker!!](https://plnkr.co/edit/VaS2ezGsHkvCF7VpRAeM?p=preview)

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `:host(...)` selector combined with `@HostBinding()` like:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp',
  styles: `
  :host([type-default]) {
    background-color: red;
  }

  :host([type-header]) {
    background-color: blue;
  }

  :host([type-main]) {
    background-color: green;
  }
`
})
export class MyComponent {
  @Input()
  @HostBinding('component-type')
  componentType:String="type-default"
}
```

and then switch style like

```
<header>
  <my-comp componentType="type-header"></my-comp>
</header>

<main>
  <my-comp componentType="type-main"></my-comp>
</main>

<my-comp></my-comp>
```

You can also apply a class from the outside like in your question and then use the `:host(...)` selector like

```
:host(.customStyle1) {
```

Then you don't need this part

```
  @Input()
  @HostBinding('component-type')
  componentType:String="type-default"
```

but this way might be beneficial if you want to combine styling with other configuration settings for the component.

Comment: That's interesting but then you have to define all possible styles inside my-comp component. Would there be a way that this is dynamic? Say, I want to use my-comp somewhere so I can create a wrapper component where I define the styles I want and then use ```template: `<my-comp></my-comp>```

Comment: You can style a component from the outside using `::ng-deep` (was `/deep/` previously)

Comment: Looks good, but it says in documentation that this will be deprecated in the feature. I thought this would be a really common issue for companies with different products that use similar components. Isn´t there a "best" way to tackle this?

Comment: I know, this comment is quite confusing. It won't be deprecated before there isn't a proper alternative. My guess is, that they'll deprecate the whole `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` (currently default) in favour of `Native` when all browsers support proper theming for shadow DOM natively.